# one request but n responses django rest framework, angular 6

Tags: django, angular, httprequest, httpresponse

I am not sure if this is the actual problem but it appears to be. Can someone shed some light?

When I make a request to my django backend it seems I get n number responses instead of one.

For example. I request venue objects, and I get a response of 4 objects. But I get 4 responses of 4 objects.

Here is the typescript:

```
this.venueservice.browsevenues(this.selectedcity, null)
                  .subscribe(
                    (req: any)=>{
                      this.filteredvenues = req;
                      console.log('this is the filtered venues');
                      console.log(this.filteredvenues);
                      for(let venue in this.filteredvenues){
                        let images = this.filteredvenues[venue].venueimage_set;
                        console.log('this is the venue images before ordering');
                        console.log(images);
```

..... (for loop not closed only because I am not showing that part of the code)

browse venue service:

```
browsevenues(city, queryparams){
    console.log('this is the queryparams');
    console.log(queryparams);
    let params = new HttpParams();
    (.... code hidden as not relevant ...)
    const browseurl = browsevenuesroot + String(city);
    return this.http.get(browseurl, {params: params});
  }
```

django backend:

```
class BrowseVenues(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        city = kwargs.get('city', 0)
        venuelist = Venue.objects.filter(online=True)
        (.... code hidden as not relevant ...)
        serialized = BrowseVenuesSerializer(venuelist, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data)
```

what I don't understand is why am I getting 4 responses? Shouldn't I just get one? Is it just because I am console logging and the log changes if the thing I am logging changes?

Comment: Can you provide a sample response ?

Comment: Are you sure that you get 4 responses from the backend? Are you seeing the 4 responses in the network panel with debug mode in your navigator?

Comment: I think you may  be underestimated the *JSON array response with length 4* as *4 different response*